# Batch file uploading with a flashplayer dialog

Tags: asp.net, dojo, yui, flajaxian

I'm currently looking at ways to allow people to select multiple files at once to batch upload images. I'm evaluating these options for my ASP.NET web app:

- [YUI Uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/)
- [Flajaxian](http://www.codeplex.com/FlajaxianFileUpload)
- [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)
- [Dojo Toolkit Multi file uploader](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/09/02/the-dojo-toolkit-multi-file-uploader/)

I'm leaning toward YUI because the documentation is clear and I basically already wrote the file uploaders and thumbnailers which Flajaxian provides, the javascript seems more compact too. I can't even begin evaluating Dojo because it's unclear to me how to get the parts that would integrate with .NET out of the PHP examples.

Has anyone had really good or really bad experiences with any of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's opinion but I ended up using [YUI Uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/) because that's what `flickr` uses and the project spec was basically an analysis of `flickr`'s features.

The experience of using it was essentially excellent, and being able to compare it to what `flickr` did was also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

SWFUploader seems to be the best option here. Compact, stylable with CSS, open source on code.google.com .

Answer (score 0):

Look at this one too.  It's free.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlashUpload.aspx

I'm using it in an application I'm developing for uploading multiple music files.  The author provides the source code as a VS 2008 project and the source Flash/Flex file.  Works like a charm.